# Tensorflow model saving and reusing issue

Tags: tensorflow

I train a ml model in TensorFlow and at that time the test accuracy was high so I saved the model and now after some days I load that pretrained model and this time I'm not getting the same test accuracy on same test dataset the accuracy is decreased a lot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi !You can reload the Pre-trained model and train it with a fresh dataset  and validate with the same test dataset again  if it was created in 2.x version .